# How to collapse Similar Lines in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets assume you have the following Data:

```
| COL 1 |  COl 2  | COL 3  |
| 10040 | [null]  | [null] |
| 10040 | [null]  |   Y    |
| 10040 |   Y     | [null] |
| 10070 | [null]  | [null] |
| 10070 |   Y     | [null] |
```

Is there any way using purely SQL to group by "COL 1" and collapse the data down to this:

```
| COL 1 |  COL 2  |  COL 3  |
| 10040 |    Y    |    Y    |
| 10070 |    Y    | [null]  |
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What would the result be if you also had a second value in one of the columns? Or are they only null and Y?

Comment: The only values were [null] and Y. Boolean, basically. The simple GROUP BY suggested by Barak Kedem below did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is what you need, but you can use many ways doing it such as:

There is no simplify then that:

```
select col1, max(col2), max(col3)
  from table 
 group by col1;
```

If you like, please comment and I will give you an example with an analytic function such as rank.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of a simple group by. This answer totally worked. Thanks so much!